# Adding jars to an application in application.xml?

Tags: java, weblogic, application.xml

I have a java application which needs to be deployed in the weblogic server. I am currently making the ear file for that application. My ear file has an ejb jar inside. I want to add log4j2 jars to this application. So my folder structure is

```
> Project-Name-
>     --Ear-Content
>         --APP-INF
>             --lib -> log4j2 jars
>             --classes - > log4j2.xml
>         --META-INF->application.xml, MANIFEST.MF, weblogic-application.xml
>         --Project-Name.jar
```

Currently I have put the jars in APP-INF folder/lib and in META-INF/application.xml I have put the jars in modules. Here is my application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC '-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.3//EN' 'http://java.sun.com/dtd/application_1_3.dtd'>
<application>
  <display-name>ProjectName</display-name>
  <description>ProjectName</description>

  <module>
        <ejb>ProjectName.jar</ejb>

  </module>
  <module>
        <java>lib/log4j-api-2.1.jar</java>

  </module>
  <module>
  <java>lib/log4j-core-2.1.jar</java>
  </module>


</application>
```

But it is not taking the log4j jars. Any solutions ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only packaging up one application, I would highly recommend using a war file instead of an ear since it is simpler. Otherwise you may need to package your current `Project-Name.jar` into a war file and then package that into the ear.

See a tutorial like [the one here](http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=1952)

That said - you should not need to explicitly reference the log4j libraries in your application.xml file with `module` tags. From the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/classloading.htm#WLPRG319):

> The classes and libraries stored under APP-INF/classes and APP-INF/lib
>   are available to all modules in the Enterprise Application. The
>   application classloader always attempts to resolve class requests by
>   first looking in APP-INF/classes, then APP-INF/lib.

Last but not least, if it seems like Weblogic is not using the classes you want it to and is instead using the defaults, in your case `log4j 1.2` vs `log4j 2`, you will need to set the following in your application.xml to tell Weblogic which one to use:

```
<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>org.apache.log4j.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

Comment: I removed the modules and added this, it worked! Thanks!